# I want to fix rectangle size while cropping image in android

Tags: android, image, crop

I want to fix the rectangle size while cropping image. How shall i do it. Any help wil b appreciated. My current code looks something as given below.

```
 // call android default gallery
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 // ******** code for crop image
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);

intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem or not?i have got same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, Use this code...

```
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 2);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("image-path", root);
```

Comment: wht shld root contain

Comment: how do i get tht path. the image is in gallery of emulator

Comment: can u pls write down the path for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri,int responseCode,int xRation,int yRation) {
        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", xRation);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", yRation);
            // indicate output X and Y
//          cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
//          cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
            File f = createNewFile("CROP_");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            Uri mCropImagedUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCropImagedUri);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, responseCode);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: whr shld i put this code. nd wht r the values for picUri,xRation,yRation. whn shld performCorp be called